# Swapping canonical urls

Tags: google, google-search-console, google-search, 301-redirect, canonical-url

Let's say I have previously registered a domain **blab.la** and have already submitted it to google search console, it is indexed and available in search results.

Now, I have purchased another domain **blabla.com** and would like it to appear in search results instead of **blab.la** while all links in **blabla.com** redirect to **blab.la**. What would be the best way to do it?

The reason why I want to do it is because I was not experienced enough when I purchased **blab.la** and did not know that you cannot retarget a **.la** website for worldwide exposure according to Google (while in other search engines you can remove targeting). I do not want to receive traffic from that specific country which already happens so I have purchased another domain in the **.com** zone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Transfer entire blab.la to blabla.com
- 301 Redirect blab.la to blabla.com
- Add both sites to Google Search Console
- Use Change of Address option in Google Search Console of blab.la and redirect it to blabla.com

Wait for few days to get backlinks juice of blab.la redirected to blabla.com.

For more details, see official guide:

```
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en
```